# How to generate an EXCEL with 2 or more worksheets using sp_makewebtask in SQL Server 2005

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2005

Is there any approach I can provide more worksheets for my report using SQL Server 2005. We have an automated report that needs to be in a single excel file but i don't know how to do it.

I tried this below but not able to accomplish what i want cause there are only 1 sheet created.

Can anyone give me a better way to solve this? Thank you..

```
`EXEC sp_makewebtask 
@OUTPUTFILE = 'C:\Bi-Monthly\CustomerTouch.XLS',
@QUERY =@QUERY ,   
@colheaders =1, 
@FixedFont=0,@lastupdated=0,@resultstitle=@Title,

insert into OPENROWSET('Microsoft.Jet.OLEDB.4.0', 
'Excel 8.0;Database=C:\Bi-Monthly\CustomerTouch.XLS;', 
'SELECT * FROM [Sheet2$]') SELECT TOP 100 * FROM inmast`
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would recommend using SSIS instead, you will have much more control.

Here is an example:

http://cavemansblog.wordpress.com/2009/04/17/ssis-export-data-from-sql-server-2005-to-excel/

You can define a set of queries as `SQL Source` and then Send them to multiple `Excel Destination` for each worksheet you want in the file.

Comment: but, Martin.. How can the SQL JOB trigger this SSIS that i created to run..? I did some research from yesterday and today. But all i see is running it using SSIS. But i want SQL Job to run it. Sorry if i might be missing something im not really familiar with this approach.. This is my 1st time dealing SSIS.

Comment: Yes, you can execute SSIS package using a job - check out this - http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms139805(v=sql.90).aspx